# What am I doing wrong here - print out XML guid value

Tags: c#, xml

Hello I have this link with [XML](http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/data/rss). I need to take all items and print out item guid value (url to post). I am doing something wrong in this code? It prints out empty lines instead of content.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/data/rss");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (reader.Name == "guid")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Value); // Prints out empty strings instead of URL
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("end.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Also, it is printing 2 lines when we see that I have 3 items with GUID's in them, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code accesses *node* element (`guid`), while the value you want is a *text element*. You need to advance reader to get inner text, like here:

```
if (reader.Name == "guid")
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
    // advance reader to current node's (guid) text value
    reader.Read();
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
}
```

Also, any reason not to try LINQ to XML here? It's fairly easy and for simple case like this I think way more readable:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/data/rss");
var links = document.Descendants("guid").Select(n => n.Value);
foreach (var link in links)
{
    Console.WriteLine(link);
}
```

Comment: Okey, it worked just fine, but can you help me with the second problem? Why it is only printing out 2 post url's when I clearly have 3

Comment: @Qmal: I see only **2** `<guid>` nodes in the linked XML.

Comment: Ahh, the third one was private and was available only to me. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if you print:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
```

Try using Linq to Xml to get the guid element values:

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/data/rss");
 var query = (from c in loaded.Descendants("guid")
                    select c.Value).ToList();
```